# Rails API Method Argument Syntax Challenges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, oauth-2.0

I'm working with the STRAVA api (strava-api-v3). I set up a @client using:

```
@client = Strava::Api::V3::Client.new(:access_token => "...numbers...")
```

I am able to run the following without error which proves that the @client works

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(@client.list_athlete_clubs)
```

The issues comes when I run another function with an parameter requirement:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(@client.retrieve_a_segment("997729"))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Psych::SyntaxError ((<unknown>): found unexpected ':' while scanning a plain scalar at line 1 column 661):
```

app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:8:in `home'

I think there is an issue with how I am passing the argument to the function. I'm not sure the correct way to pass it. The documentation readme looks like this:

```
@client.retrieve_a_segment(:some_id)
```

Thanks

Comment: To clarify if the error is in the JSON parsing or in the API you could try separating the steps... segment = @client.retrieve_a_segment(997729)  and then JSON.pretty_generate(segment)

Comment: I've tried that and the error is in the @client. retrieve_a_segment(997729), not in the JSON parsing

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that for the version of RVM that I had the YAML function had some sideeffects. The solution to the problem was to go into the boot.rb file and add:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

all good